# How to edit a text file in a ZIP or RAR archive, without manual extract/compression?

Tags: password, text-editor, file-archives

I have a text file in a compressed file (RAR/ZIP). On my desktop, I happen to be able to edit it, and then WinRAR or 7-Zip sends a message saying the text file was changed and asking if I want to update it.

The same thing seems impossible to do in Android 8.1.0. I have tried ZArchiver, ZArchiver Pro, RAR from Rarlab, and several text editors, but in the end, the zip file is never updated with the changes I make in the text.

I also tried MiXplorer and MiX Archive (the archive plugin), and although it's a powerful tool, it's not working. When I try to save the text file, it says "Not supported!" regardless of the zip or rar file. I wonder if it's because the archive has a password. It also seems it can't open the zip file directly from the Dropbox app, providing the same "not supported!" error.

Does anyone know a way? Or a way that allows me to set a password on a text file that is cross-platform between Android and Windows? Any hint, or any other tool I could try? In the settings of MiXplorer, it doesn't seem anything could help.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** just "edit" an entry in-place in a RAR/ZIP file because it's compressed.

You'll need to decompress it, edit the files as needed, and then re-compress it.

WinRAR (Windows) do this steps automatically. Up to now, I couldn't find an application do like WinRAR (Windows) on Android OS.

Comment: I beg to differ here slightly...I tested the feature with mixplorer and it works, but your reasoning is pretty much correct, this operation is simply not supported 'out of the box'

Comment: Are you sure MiXplorer do it without decompressing? I think because of built-in text editor, it were worked.

Comment: Pretty sure, I reckon it does it the same way as Winrar on Windows does, the process may be 'automatic' but essentially you **don't manually decompress** the file

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Actually, the answerer is right. The only difference between the app you mention is that it hides the unpacking and repacking procedures to the user. Edit: granted, you don't manually decompress anything, as the program handles everything.